# How can i save div content into a PHP Session?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

*i just start to learning php & ajax, so pls be gentle.*

I have a clickable Content. When the user Click on a map, the Point Value is shown in a div. After he choose one Point he can go to the next step.

Now i want to save the content of the div into a php session. How can i put the div content into a php session and go forward to the next step?

**I tried this:**

```
  $("#btn").click(function()
{

    var red = $(this).attr("id");
     $(".tab").text(red);

    $.post("backend.php", {"cpl": red});
});
```

**Backend.php**

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['var1'] = $_POST['cpl'];
 ?>
```

But he dont do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is this breaking down?  Does the red var in your javascript get set correctly?  Does the POST data get sent correctly to your PHP?  Is the listener firing correctly?

Comment: red ist set correctly. The POST data get not sent correctly

Comment: try removing the quotes from "cpl" in the .post

Comment: You said:"How can i put the div content into a php session and go forward to the next step" but why are you taking only the id of your div? and not the content?

Comment: Is that all you have within that click... anly these two lines ? where's is the send() method... ? would you share that part

Comment: Christain is right your just taking the id it looks like. You want `html()` or `.text()`

Comment: @hex494D49 OP doesn't need any send() method.  It's part of .post

Comment: @ChrisWillard Thanks man, I'm not a jQuery fan :)

Comment: By the way your code is just fine, and it works

Comment: Try this `if(session_start()){ $_SESSION['var1'] = "Test"; echo $_SESSION['var1']; }else{ echo "No session" }` to be sure that there's no problem on the server part.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a php script, that receive the content of this div (get this content with jQuery), and store it in PHP session var.

Comment: i can get the content to jquery. But how can i store it in a PHP Session?

Comment: yes, the PHP script receive the HTML content in a post or get value, i do not see any problem to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

*index.php*

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<div id="someDiv">
    <em>This</em> is the content you'll store in session.
</div>

<div id="saveDivContent">
    Click here to store the content.
</div>

<pre>
<?php var_dump($_SESSION); ?>
</pre>

<form id="hiddenForm" style="display:none">
<input type="hidden" id="sendDivContent" name="content"></input>
</form>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hiddenForm").bind("submit", function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            async:true,
            data:$("#hiddenForm").serialize(),
            error:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Handle error.");
            },
            success:function (data, textStatus) {
                console.log("Handle success");
            },
            type:"POST",
            // url:"save_content.php"
            url:"\/link\/to\/file\/that\/saves_div_content.php"
        });
        return false;
    });
    $("#saveDivContent").bind("click", function (event) {
        var divContent = $("#someDiv").html();
        $("#sendDivContent").val(divContent);
        $("#hiddenForm").submit();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

*saves_div_content.php:*

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    if( isset($_POST['content']) && $_POST['content'] !== null && $_POST['content'] !== null )
        $_SESSION['div_content'] = $_POST['content'];
}
/* EOF */
```

*saves_div_content.php* has the only really relevant code, but I'm prone to giving full examples.
The other thing that might confuse is the irrelevant AJAX mechanism. You could well make that form point at *index.php* with a POST method(`<form action="index.php" method="POST">`) and add the code in *saves_div_content.php* to the head of *index.php*.

**You can perfectly avoid using two separate files.**